# Multiple selected values QGIS form save to PostgreSQL

Tags: qgis, postgis

I need save multiple selections in QGIS form to PostgreSQL table. My form is:
[image]

How could I save the selected values ​​in the PostgreSQL table?

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to make sure that your PostgreSQL column can contain your selection, which will be saved as an array ({'Macrofitas','Sedimentos'}).
If you export you table to Postgresql dump, this will probably be default.